# How to access relation of relation in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

how to access $employee->role()->roleName()->first()->name

as i can't access relation of relation models:

[You Can check the Collection by clicking here](https://jsfiddle.net/01g693xq/1/)

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/01g693xq/1/embed/"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$employee->role()->roleName()->name
```

Comment: Please note that the first answer worked wiz me.   $employee->role->roleName->first()->name